# Why does find . -name foo* fail?

Tags: linux

OK, probably a stupid question, but why doesn't this work?

```
find . -name Orna* -ls
```

It seems that "find" should be able to handle this simple request... Am I missing something here?  This should be a basic execution of the "find" command, but linux is being stupid, or maybe I am.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `-ls` there?

Comment: @chris It's like `ls -l` Gives the long description of files.

Comment: "but linux is being stupid", `find` is not part of Linux, it's GNU software. And it's not `find`'s fault, it's your shell. "It seems that "find" should be able to handle this simple request..." Maybe it seems like it, but it doesn't, in which case you should RTFM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct way of using Find Command are the following phrases

```sh
find . -type f -name "filename"  # this command used to find files from the curent dir 
find . -type d -name "dir name"  # this command used to find dirs from the curent dir 
find /. -type f -name "filename" # this command used to find files from the system 
find /. -type d -name "dir name" # this command used to find dirs from the system
```

I wish it be a helpful for you

Comment: Fixed the comment format (POSIX shells use `#`, not `//`, for comments).

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the name parameter so the shell doesn't expand the wildcard, e.g.

```sh
find . -name "Orna*" -ls
```

Comment: From the `-name` section of `man find`:  "Don't forget to enclose the pattern in quotes in order to protect it  from  expansion  by  the shell."

Answer (score 2):

To explain the "why" a little more than existing answers do -- wildcards are expanded by the shell *before* the command being invoked is run. Thus, let's say your current directory contains files `Orna1` and `Orna2`.

In that case, when you run

```
find . -name Orna* -ls
```

...what's actually invoked by the shell is:

```
find . -name Orna1 Orna2 -ls
```

...thus, `find` never sees the wildcard expression at all!

---

Quoting the expansion, as in:

```
find . -name 'Orna*' -ls
```

...prevents the shell from trying to expand the wildcard before running your command, thus preventing this issue.

Comment: The best answer.